# Trigger a method in background in iOS at a particular time

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, time, localnotification

Case: If your set a time 8:00 am and Days as Monday and Wednesday, then we notify the user at 8:00 am Monday and Wednesday. What are the best ways to handle this situation.

So far i searched, UILocalNotofication and NSTimer. Other that these things to handle?

Answer (score 0):

This Apple example on how to do it with `UILocalNotification`

```
- (void)scheduleAlarmForDate:(NSDate*)theDate
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray*    oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    // Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.
    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    // Create a new notification.
    UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (alarm)
    {
        alarm.fireDate = theDate;
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
        alarm.alertBody = @"Time to wake up!";

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    }
}
```

Apple doesn't let you run NSTimers on the background (There were some security issues), This [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) that explains how to run tasks in the background and have some code examples like the one above.

Comment: So i have to schedule two alarams. Thankyou @BlackSheep

Answer (score 0):

I have read about other way to set alarms [in this blog](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/)

Otherwise, I think you will have to use notifications.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit|  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: now];
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday: 2] ; 
[componentsForFireDate setHour: 8] ; 
[componentsForFireDate setMinute:0] ;
[componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;

NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi!"] ;
notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Updates added for that week!"] forKey:@"subtitle"];
notification.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
notification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;
```